# Return ISO-8601 dates with custom ObjectMapper in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-time, jackson-databind

I want my `LocalDateTime`s to be returned as ISO-8601 strings (e.g. `"2020-10-12T10:57:15Z"`) from my Spring REST Controllers. This has worked previously, but now that I'm using a custom Jackson2 `ObjectMapper` these dates are instead being returned as arrays: `[2020, 10, 12, 10, 57, 15, 200000000]`.

Why is this happening and how can I customize the `ObjectMapper` while still returning ISO-8601 dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JacksonAutoConfiguration` creates an `ObjectMapper` with the `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature turned off, which returns `LocalDateTimes` as ISO-8601 strings. When you provide a custom `ObjectMapper` this default auto-configuration is turned off.

This can be solved by, instead of providing a custom `ObjectMapper`, providing a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`. This bean will be used by `JacksonAutoConfiguration` to customize the `ObjectMapper` while maintaining the auto-configured behaviour such as turning off the `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer objectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> {
            // Customize the ObjectMapper while maintaining the auto-configuration
        };
    }
}
```